# libviso2 cannot run

Tags: ros, libviso2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all :

I'm trying to do the libviso2 now . There is a README .txt

1. Move to libviso2 root directory
2. Type 'cmake .'
3. Type 'make'
4. Run './viso2 path/to/sequence/2010_03_09_drive_0019'

I done the first 3 steps ,but I really don't know how to do the last line ....

What is path to sequence ???  It's that a directory ?

Can somebody helping me ~~~~~ please ..... Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232588/libviso2-cannot-run/) by [wendyZzzz](https://answers.ros.org/users/26319/wendyzzzz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-04-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems it's not ROS related question.
libviso2 can evaluate in ROS with viso2_ros package

I recommend referring below link:

http://wiki.ros.org/viso2?distro=indigo

---

Originally posted by [LeeJaemin](https://answers.ros.org/users/5294/leejaemin/) with karma: 26 on 2016-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0